# Crear un arreglo que no repita palabras C++ strings

Tags: c++, array

Estoy haciendo un programa en C++ que toma palabras de un archivo .txt e inserta cada una en un arregla, el problema es que NO se debe repetir ninguna palabra, y estoy teniendo complicaciones en esa parte.
Actualmente solo estoy trabajando en esa parte, el menú solo funciona de momento con 1.

/ Proyecto.cpp : 
//

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int menu()    //
{
    cout << "Proyecto\n";
    cout << "0. Salida\n";
    cout << "1. Lectura de archivos\n";
    cout << "2. Busqueda \n";
    cout << "Opcion: ";
    int opcion;
    cin >> opcion;
    return opcion;
}


void Almacenar(string Arreglo[200], int tamanio = 200)
{
    string palabra;
    int valor, i=0;
    ifstream ficheroEntrada;
    ficheroEntrada.open("Entrada.txt");

    while (!ficheroEntrada.eof())                                   //eof para comprobar que no hemos llegado al final del archivo.
    {

            while (ficheroEntrada >> palabra)
            {

                bool comp = false;
                while (i < tamanio)
                {

                    int j = 0;

                    while (j <= i && comp == false)
                    {


                        if (palabra.compare(Arreglo[j])==0)
                        {


                            comp = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {

                            j++;
                        }
                    }
                    if (comp == false)
                    {
                        Arreglo[i] = palabra;

                        i++;

                    }

                }
            }
    }
    ficheroEntrada.close();
}
int main()
{
    int opcion, tamanio = 250;
    string Arreglo[200];
    do
    {
        opcion = menu();
        switch (opcion)
        {
        case 1: Almacenar(Arreglo, tamanio); break;

        }
    } while (opcion != 0);
    system("pause");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

cambia los dos `while` anidados por un bucle `for`. Realmente solo necesitas iterar una vez la colección para saber si una palabra está o no presente en la lista, luego con un único bucle debería ser suficiente.

También eliminaría el chequeo de `eof`. Este flag solo se activa **después** de una lectura que alcance el final del archivo y en ese momento ya te habrá fallado el `while` que lee las palabras... no es necesaria tanta redundancia.

```
while (ficheroEntrada >> palabra)
{
  bool duplicada = false;

  for( size_t i=0; i<tamanio; i++ )
  {
    duplicada = palabra == Arreglo[i];
    if( duplicada ) break;
  }

  if( !duplicada )
  {
    Arreglo[tamanio] = palabra;
    tamanio++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No reinventes la rueda, la [STL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library) ofrece contenedores que *eliminan* duplicados si sabes como usarlos, te presento [`std::map` [image]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map). Adaptando la propuesta de [eferion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/213174/2742):

```
std::map<std::string, int> palabras;

while (ficheroEntrada >> palabra)
{
    ++palabras[palabra];
}
```

El operador de indizado del mapa ([`operator []` [image]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at)) devuelve el elemento en el índice indicado y si el índice no existía previamente: lo crea.

Por lo tanto, con el código anterior, tendrás las palabras únicas del texto leído, cuántas veces aparecieron y además las recibirás en orden alfabético:

```
for (const auto &aparicion : palabras)
    std::cout << "La palabra '" << aparicion.first << "' apareció " << aparicion.second << " veces en el texto\n";
```